# Python macros for method parameters

Tags: python, macros

I'm doing a bunch of unit tests for a bunch of methods I have in my code and started to realize I could really condense this code block down if I could do some sort of macro that would just take care of all my insertions for me.

This is an example of a method I would use, however the only differences is the parameters `c_unit_case` also `c_test_case` are based on the methods in lib.

```
def test_case(filepath):
    tests = parsedfile(filepath)
    for unittests in tests:
         print lib.c_test_case(unittests.params[0])
```

I'm looking for something sort of like this.

```
GENERIC_CASE(method_name, params, filepath)
     (tests) = parsedfile(filepath)
        for unittests in (tests):
             args += unittests.(params)
             print lib.(method_name)(args)
```

Is it possible to do this type of thing in Python?

Comment: While not a complete answer, you can accomplish `lib.(method_name)(args)` with `getattr(lib, method_name)(args)`

Comment: Are you actually using the `unittest` module to execute these? If not, what's actually running all the `test_case` functions? Can you clarify this statement: *"however the only differences is the parameters c_unit_case also c_unit_case based on the methods in lib."* The wording there is a bit confusing.

Comment: There are a LOT of test frameworks out there that have already solved this problem for you.  `unittest` (in the stdlib) is one, as is `nose`, `py.test`, ... see https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy

Comment: @roippi I remember looking into them and they are good. I'm am just using this more as an example. Also `unittests` has an array called `params` that grow.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see if this works:

```
def test_case(method_name, filepath, *args):
    tests = parsedfile(filepath)
    print (method_name(*args))
```

*args in the signature of the function lets you put in as many additional arguments as you'd like. Calling method_name(*args) unrolls the arguments into the parameter.

This should handle a variable number of arguments.

This is what it would sort of look like the way you had it:

```
GENERIC_CASE(method_name, filepath, *params)
    (tests) = parsedfile(filepath)
    for unittests in (tests):
         args += unittests.(*params)
         print lib.(method_name)(args)
```

I'm not 100% if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to work. What to my understanding you need to fill in parameters to the method before putting them into another method. for instance, method1(a) can't go into method1(methoda()). You need to fill in the parameters correct?

Comment: @progenhard this is somewhat difficult to talk about as I don't think it is completely clear yet, so I may still be off. But, if method1 has a signature "def method1(a, b, c)" and methoda() returns (a, b, c), then calling them like so method1(*methoda()) should unroll the tuple returned by methoda() and align them with the correct parameters in method1